# Can self be used to access object attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to validate a few image fields and I don't know if it's possible to use a variable representing the field's name and a for loop to iterate over the model's attributes?

```
    class Guitar(models.Model):
         images0 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

         def clean(self):
         images = ['images0', ...]
         for idx, val in enumerate(images):
            if self[val].size > 2000000:
```

So it is possible to use `self` like this?

```
self[val].size == self.images0.size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

After reading the python documentation for those functions, you might consider writing your code like this:

```
 def clean(self):
     images = ['images0', ...]
     for idx, val in enumerate(images):
         if hasattr(self, val):
             image = getattr(self, val)
             if image.size > 2000000:
                 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it like that. Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr